# Golang. Sending data to template doesn't works

Tags: go

I want to know what is the true way to send any data to template (the html/template package)? My code is below:

```
var templates = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(
    path.Join(this.currentDirectory, "views/base.html"),
    path.Join(this.currentDirectory, "views/main/test.html"),
))

templates.Execute(response, map[string]string{
    "Variable": "Тест!",
})
```

And that's template:

```
{{define "content"}}
{{ .Variable }}
{{end}}
```

I will be thankful!

Comment: There's no question here. What are you trying to do, or what problem are you having?

Comment: I don't see my variable value instead of {{ .Variable }}.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your template has a name, `"content"`, so you need to specifically execute that template.

```
templates.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "content", map[string]string{
    "Variable": "Тест!",
})
```

You may not be parsing what you think. From the `template.ParseFiles` documentation (emphasis mine)

> The returned template's name will have the (base) name and (parsed) **contents of the first file**

Try using:

```
t, err := template.New("base").ParseFiles("base.html", "test.html")
if err != nil { ... }
t.Execute(response, variables)
```

And [here's a playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/aKs9Mrxr0t) if it helps.

Comment: Thanks that works, but the «content» template redefines another «content» template from the base.html file.

Comment: Then please show a full example. If you have conflicting names, you're going to have problems.

Comment: I think your code just prints the one of templates.

Comment: I'm still guessing, because you have yet to show a full example.

Comment: I try to explain. I have two templates — test.html and base.html. The base.html contains «base» template which contains the «content» template. The test.html is used to extend first template (to redefine «content» template).

This's the link to archive with my example: http://rghost.ru/57363824.

Comment: @Razip: did you see that latest edit? That change will parse both files for you, starting with the "base" template

Comment: Yes, I did. But your example works with templates are contained in variables. Can you show an example with the ParseFiles function?

Comment: All the parsing methods are inter-related, check out the source. I already showed what you need by using a pre-declared template. I'll add a little more though.